# Как протестировать стратегию торговли на исторических данных?

Tags: python

Прошу помочь. Есть задание. Написание спотовой торговой стратегии и тестирование ее на исторических данных биткоина.
[image: Опис]

Есть код.

```
import backtrader as bt
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd


class GridStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        start_price = self.data.open[0]

        entry_percentages = [0.02, 0.04, 0.06]
        exit_percentage = 0.04

        self.entry_prices = []
        self.exit_prices = []
        for i in range(5):
            for percentage in entry_percentages:
                entry_price = start_price * (1 - (i + 1) * percentage)
                exit_price = entry_price * (1 + exit_percentage)

                self.entry_prices.append(entry_price)
                self.exit_prices.append(exit_price)

        self.capital = 10000
        self.order_size = self.capital / 15

        # Розміщення лімітних ордерів на купівлю відразу
        print(self.entry_prices)
        for entry_price in self.entry_prices:
            print(f'Byu. Price {entry_price}')
            self.buy(size=self.order_size, exectype=bt.Order.Limit, price=entry_price)

    def next(self):
        # Перевірка умов для продажу
        for i, position in enumerate(self.positions):
            if position:
                if self.data.close[0] >= self.exit_prices[i]:
                    self.sell(size=self.order_size, exectype=bt.Order.Limit, price=self.exit_prices[i])

api_key = 'CNi4URpmksP2o1EfuG0pihdFhDeYOAEpEIIjxqa2YTJmTWzlrAfZbCXC8NWpM5xs'
api_secret = 'udGIrUeAZlvJDnP0fHDrWcWSVUDcAUgzgTaJY57Ai3n1pcaEHf8REUaSGVwxOnIO'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
candles = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, "1 Sep, 2023", "1 Oct, 2023")

# Конвертація в DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(candles, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'close_time',
                                    'quote_asset_volume', 'number_of_trades', 'taker_buy_base_asset_volume',
                                    'taker_buy_quote_asset_volume', 'ignore'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

# Конвертуємо рядкові значення в числа
df['open'] = df['open'].astype(float)
df['high'] = df['high'].astype(float)
df['low'] = df['low'].astype(float)
df['close'] = df['close'].astype(float)
df['volume'] = df['volume'].astype(float)

df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
# Завантаження даних в backtrader
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df, open='open', high='high', low='low', close='close', volume='volume',
                           openinterest=None)

# Ініціалізація backtrader
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.addstrategy(GridStrategy)
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.TradeAnalyzer, _name="trade_stats")

# Запуск стратегії
results = cerebro.run()

# Виведення статистики
trade_stats = results[0].analyzers.trade_stats.get_analysis()
print(trade_stats)

# Візуалізація результатів
cerebro.plot()
```

Но на выводе нет ни ордеров на покупку ни на продажу. Почему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]